# Using Option Group Toggle Buttons to Filter Data in Form

Tags: filter, ms-access-2010, togglebutton

I have an Access 2010 database with a form that pulls up a list of all of the students that a teacher teaches.  One of the fields is "Classperiod"; each teacher teaches 5 classes.  I have a set of toggle buttons in an option group (Frame 103) that I'd like to use to filter the list of records by "Classperiod".  So, for example, clicking on one of the toggle buttons would only show students from a particular class.  Here's the code that I have for the option group in the "After Update" of the Events for the option group:

```
Private Sub Frame103_AfterUpdate()
Select Case Frame103
    Case 1
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 1"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 2
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 2"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 3
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 3"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 5
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 5"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 6
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 6"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 7
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 7"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case 8
    Me.Filter = "Schedules.Classperiod = 8"
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Case Else
    Me.FilterOn = False

   End Select
End Sub
```

Schedules is the Table that Classperiod is a field for.

Right now the code isn't doing anything.  Any suggestions would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your filter can still work if you remove your "Schedule".  Just use the fieldname:

Eg.

```
 Case 7
 Me.Filter = "Classperiod = 7"
 Me.FilterOn = True
```

The best way however, would be to restrict your record source by the data meeting your criteria:
eg:

```
Case ....
Me.RecordSource = "Select * FROM Schedules WHERE Classperiod =..."
Me.Requiry
....
```

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply -- thanks for posting it.  Unfortunately I was unable to get this to work.  I tried both of the suggestions but the records still remained unfiltered.  Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure why that would not work.  If the Form bound to the Schedule Table?  or what is the current record source for the whole Form?

Comment: The record sources is from two tables, one called "Students" and the other is the Schedules table.  The two tables are brought together by an inner join.  As best I can tell, it's bound.  Is there a way that I can tell for sure?

Comment: I have just noticed something: You should put your Code on the "On Click" event not the "After Update...This is because you used a Toggle buttons in an Option group, The value of the Option Group is changed "On Click" Event depending of which option was selected.  This should definitively work.  You could also try it on BeforeUpdate but AfterUpdate can simply not work

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but unfortunately this did not work either -- I tried it in both the "On Click" and "Before Update" but it did not work in either one.

Comment: Can you attach your db?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't -- there's too much confidential info.  I stumbled upon a work-around for this late yesterday.  I created a subform that had the same data as the form and had it reference the toggle buttons.  For whatever reason, the data in the subform responded to the toggle buttons while, as we saw, the data in the form did not.  I'm not sure why this works and the other did not, but it does.  Thank you for all of your effort in trying to help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on five different class periods, make your option group with five toggle buttons, the caption of each corresponding to a different class period e.g. toggle button 1 has caption "1" and so on. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Frame103_Click()
    Dim Caption As String
    Caption = Frame103.Controls.Item(Frame103.Value - 1).Caption
    Me.SubformName.Form.Filter = "[Classperiod] = """ & Caption & """"
    Me.SubformName.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```